# plist value not showing in tableview

Tags: ios, plist, tableview

I have a plist which is an array which has dictionary in it. I am trying to print out the name in the table view however the name doesnt show up. What I have so far is the following code

```
    self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Fetch from the app bundle... load the NSDictionary
    _qList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"plist"]];

   _qNames=[_qList valueForKey:@"Name"];


}
return self;
```

And for my table view i have

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    int index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
NSString *key = [[self.test.qNames valueForKey:@"Name"] objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *value = [self.test.qNames objectForKey:key];
[[cell textLabel] setText:value];

    return cell;
}
```

My plist structure is as follows:

Root (Array)
   -Item 0 (Dictionary)
       -Name
       -Class
       -Age
   -Item 1 (Dictionary)
        -Name
        -Class
        -Age

and so on..

I just need to figure out how to put

```
 NSDictionary *name=[self.model.qList valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

the name i return into the table view?

Comment: _qNames=[_qList valueForKey:@"Name"]; is returning the name

Comment: If qList is an array, why are you using valueForKey?  Don't you want to use objectAtIndex: to get one of the Dictionaries and then start picking out individual values?

Comment: _qNames=[_qList valueForKey:@"Name"]; is returning the 20 names I have in my plist. qlist is an array but inside that array i have an dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use Key-Value Coding(KVC) to get just the array of names(strings) from dictionaries.

For that you should use valueForKeyPath, not valueForKey

In initializer,

```
//Get the array of names
 _qNames=[_qList valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath,

```
NSString *name = [self.test.qNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell textLabel] setText:name];
```